# Implementing other layouts and views on Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am trying to create a screen like the this one. This is my design goal.

[image]

I am using `RelativeLayout` along with the `MapFragment`. But this does not look like the following screen. I appreciate your suggestions to do this in right way. Here is my code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="gps.finder.com.findermaterial.MapsActivity" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#c8e6c9">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Card View"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/details"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Card View"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="description"
                android:textColor="#666"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can any one tell me how can I do this?

Comment: post your xml code here . what have you done till now ?

Comment: @SagarNayak I added my xml code. Please check it or you can suggest me any useful links.

Comment: is this necessary to make your map fill the entire screen . because even if it fills your screen you cant really see it. so i suggest you keep the map to the limit where it is really visible .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OnTouchListener on those Views just return true at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `TextView`s clickable adding

```
android:clickable="true
```

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Card View"
    android:textColor="#222"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- give an id to your inner relativelayout.
- set a clicklistener to your layout .

**Example**

*(in your xml code)*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="gps.finder.com.findermaterial.MapsActivity" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#c8e6c9">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
.....
..... (this is your remaining xml )
```

***in activity-***

```
findViewById(R.id.container_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //leave this empty. or you can write some functionality here.
        }
    });
```

this will solve your problem.

please let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Hello - thank for your response. I need design guide too. I uploaded an sample image and that is my goal design. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: first implement this answer in your code and let me know if it worked. then we can proceed further.